# can a "hook" execute a shell command in mutt?

Tags: mutt

Is there any way to have a "hook" execute a shell command? Either through a:
- 
- tick marks (``)
- through "a macro"

I checked the [neomutt documentation](https://neomutt.org/feature/global-hooks#targetText=Run%20a%20command%20when%20NeoMutt%20shuts%20down%2C%20before%20closing%20the%20last%20mailbox&targetText=This%20feature%20implements%20a%20hook,useful%20to%20users%20of%20notmuch) and it says that the hook command can execute something with backticks:

```
shutdown-hook 'echo `mbsync -a`'
```

But whenever I do that, I get:

```
echo: unknown command
```

I tried doing a:

```
shutdown-hook 'echo `ls`'
```

and I still get the same error. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Did you place these commands in your `.muttrc` file?

This does work for me, inserting in `.muttrc` file

```
startup-hook 'echo `echo did it > /tmp/mutt-did-it`'
```

then running mutt, the file `/tmp/mutt-did-it` then contains `did it`. It does also work with folder and send hooks.